# Erro ao converter tipos

Tags: java, array, conversão-de-tipo

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade que consiste em criar um array de imoveis baseado em algumas regras que são fornecidas pelo txt. O código dá erro e não sei o que está ocorrendo.

Um detalhe que quando comento a linha `valor = Integer.parseInt(parts[contvetor]);` funciona normal. Mas a variável `contvetor` está declarada, então não sei o que está ocorrendo.

Preciso correr esse array de string convertendo para ir utilizando os valores no código e criar o tabuleiro do banco imobiliario.

```
  try { 
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
  String line = br.readLine(); 
  while(line!=null){ 
  sb.append(line); 
  sb.append(System.lineSeparator()); 
  line = br.readLine(); 
  //System.out.println(line); 
  } 

  String everything = sb.toString(); 
  //System.out.println(everything);
  String[] parts = everything.split(";");
  //System.out.println(parts[8]);
  valor = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
  valorinicial = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); //variavel valor recebe o inteiro convertido do txt
//  int[] idades = new int[valor]; //define o tamnho do vetor
  ArrayList<Imovel> vetor = new ArrayList<Imovel>();  
  for(int cont=0;cont<valorinicial;cont++){ //estrutura de repeticao que inicia o tabuleiro
      if(cont==0){
          ClubeSocial start = new ClubeSocial(); //clubesocial eh a classe start
          start.setstart();         //isso faz com que os 4 primeiros valores lidos no arquivos ja tenham sido utilizados parts[0-3]
          vetor.add(start);
          contvetor = 4;
          valor = Integer.parseInt(parts[contvetor]);
      }
      for(int cont2=0;cont2<6;cont2++){
            if(cont2==0 || cont2==1){ //nao preciso da id e nao preciso da casa, porque o for ja faz isso, entao desconsidero as 2
              cont2++;
              contvetor++;
          }
          //abaixo olhamos valor casa para ver se cai 2 ou 3 [passe a vez ou add imovel]
          if(valor==2){ //adiciona um passe a vez e faz cont2 ficar maior que 5 para que termine essa linha de instrucao e comece a prox
              passeavez pass = new passeavez();
              pass.setpass();
              vetor.add(pass);
              cont2 = 6;
              contvetor++;
          }
          else{ //no caso o valor é 3 que é pra add imovel
              cont2++; //incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 4ª valor dos 6 da linha
              if(valor == 1){
                  Residencia residencia = new Residencia();
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++; //incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 5ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  residencia.setPreco(valor);
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 6ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  residencia.setAluguel(valor);
                  vetor.add(residencia);
                  cont2 = 6;
              }
              else if(valor == 2){
                  Comercio comercio = new Comercio();
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 5ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  comercio.setPreco(valor);
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 6ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  comercio.setAluguel(valor);
                  vetor.add(comercio);
                  cont2 = 6;
              }
              else if(valor == 3){
                  Industria industria = new Industria();
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 5ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  industria.setPreco(valor);
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 6ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  industria.setAluguel(valor);
                  vetor.add(industria);
                  cont2 = 6;
              }
              else if(valor == 4){
                  Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 5ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  hotel.setPreco(valor);
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 6ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  hotel.setAluguel(valor);
                  vetor.add(hotel);
                  cont2 = 6;
              }
              else if(valor == 5){
                  Hospital hospital = new Hospital();
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 5ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  hospital.setPreco(valor);
                  cont2++;
                  contvetor++;//incrementa o valor do contador para pegar o 6ª valor dos 6 da linha
                  hospital.setAluguel(valor);
                  vetor.add(hospital);
                  cont2 = 6;
              }
          }
      }
  }

  System.out.println("pqp" + valor);

  } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  finally{ 
  //br.close(); 
  } 


  } 

  }
```

Erro abaixo:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
> 2"
>     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>     at jogo.main.main(main.java:45)
> ```

Comment: O problema não é a aspa? Tenta dar um replace de " para vazio

Comment: O que `parts[contvetor]` retorna? Não tem um espaço vazio ai?

Comment: O problema parece ser o `\n` antes do 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que existe uma quebra de linha e quando tenta converter para Integer com o parse acontece o erro, uma solução seria adicionar o .trim() para remover isso e funcionar normalmente, ficando assim :

```
valor = Integer.parseInt(parts[contvetor].trim());
```

Você também pode tentar fazer isso :

```
valor = Integer.parseInt(parts[contvetor].replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\t", "").replaceAll("\n", ""));
```